# Expected value of a maximum of BM

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I want to find the value of the following expectation: $$E[max(B_s,B_t)^2]$$ with $$ s,t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$$

We can also write it as $$E[B_s^2 .\mathbb{1}_{B_s>B_t}]+E[B_t^2 . \mathbb{1}_{B_t>B_s}]$$

Now we notice that $$E[\mathbb{1}_{B_s>B_t}]=E[\mathbb{1}_{B_t>B_s}]$$ since $s,t$ are interchangeable, but I do not have the independance of the random variables to separate the expectation and find $$\frac{s+t}{2}$$

In fact this result seems a bit strange to me since $$E[max(B_s,B_t)^2]+E[min(B_s,B_t)^2]=s+t$$ which would mean both $$max(B_s,B_t)^2$$ and $$min(B_s,B_t)^2$$ have the same expected value.

Do you have any hints on how to rigorously prove or disprove my heuristic result?

Comment: I would imagine that the easiest way to solve this would be to use that $\max(a,b) = \frac 12 (a+b + |a-b|)$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I am back after a bit of thinking, I think I understand why both expected values are the same and thus the result, although It it still a bit unclear to me intuitively.

Since the distributions of $(B_s)_{s\geq 0}$ and $(-B_s)_{s\geq 0}$ are the same we have

$$E[min(B_s,B_t)]=E[min(-B_s,-B_t)]$$ so $$E[max(B_s,B_t)^2]=E[(-min(-B_s,-B_t))^2]=E[min(-B_s,-B_t)^2]=E[min(B_s,B_t)^2]$$

Comment: Assume $s<t$. If you use the facts that $B_s\sim \mathcal{N}(0,s)$ and $B_t|B_s\sim \mathcal{N}(B_s,t-s)$ you'll find that $$f_{B_s,B_t}(x,y)=f_{B_t|B_s}(y|x)f_{B_s}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{s\left(t-s\right)}}\exp\left(-\frac{tx^{2}-2sxy+sy^{2}}{2s\left(t-s\right)}\right)$$ You should now check that $$\mathbb{E}\big[\big(\max(B_s,B_t)\big)^2\big]=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\max(x,y))^2f_{B_s,B_t}(x,y)\mathrm{d}A=\frac{s+t}{2}$$ $$\mathbb{E}\big[\big(\min(B_s,B_t)\big)^2\big]=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\min(x,y))^2f_{B_s,B_t}(x,y)\mathrm{d}A=\frac{s+t}{2}$$